# Как проверить, что поток NSThread заблокирован?

Tags: objective-c, многопоточность, posix, pthread

Давно хотел узнать, возможно ли для тестирования (unit testing) сделать следующее:

**Можно ли добавить в NSThread метод, который будет показывать, заблокирован (остановлен) ли данный поток или нет?**

Я предполагаю, что, если эта задача в принципе решается, было бы удобно сделать отдельную категорию NSThread+IsBlocked, содержащую такой метод и вполне достойную своего отдельного репозитория на Github ;)

Прямо сейчас я занимаюсь NSCondition - вот цепь вызовов, которую для остановки потока делает -[NSCondition wait]:

```
[NSCondition wait] 
pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003
_pthread_cond_wait
__psynch_cvwait
```

Кроме NSCondition есть множество других способов блокировать/останавливать потоки NSThread: dispatch semaphores, NSConditionLock, [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:] и т.п. - я знаю Objective-C лишь на уровне iOS-разработчика, поэтому не имею представления, возможно ли написать такой метод, который будет показывать факт блокировки потока сразу для всех этих способов. Буду признателен даже за метод, работающий только с NSCondition и __psynch_cvwait.

Вот простой пример того, чего я хотел бы добиться (искомый метод - **isBlocked**):

```
// Some test case
// ...

__block NSThread *thread;
NSCondition *condition = [NSCondition alloc] init];

dispatch_async(someQueue(), ^{
    thread = NSThread.currentThread;

    [condition lock];
    [condition wait];
    [condition unlock];
});

while(1) {
    NSLog(@"Thread is blocked: %d", thread.isBlocked);
}
```

Я не знаток чистого C и POSIX threads, поэтому, если знаете ответ, сделайте его, пожалуйста, развёрнутым.

Примечание: речь идёт именно о блокировании (остановке) потока, а не о проверке isLocked вроде "Находимся ли мы @synchronized {}?"

Comment: По моему мнению, в хорошо написанном коде такой метод не нужен и даже вреден. Тем более, на какой момент времени полученное значение валидно?

Comment: @VladD, всё верно. Я задавал вопрос главным образом для (само)образования: в какой-то момент мне стало интересно, возможно ли в принципе решить эту задачу. Реально использовать полученное решение собираюсь лишь в 1-2 исключительных частных случаях. Я надеюсь, что сам факт того, что такой вопрос задан, не будет вдохновлять людей на движение в неверном направлении, и пусть эти комментарии дополнительно послужат тому, чтобы этого не происходило!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мир - Россия 1:0 - ответ получен в топике, который параллельно с этим был открыт мной на SO: [Is it possible to check if an NSThread is blocked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468479/is-it-possible-to-check-if-an-nsthread-is-blocked).

Там см. принятый ответ. Очень изящное решение для NSCondition.

Заодно показывающее, как можно красиво модифицировать поведение классов, подменяя методы друг другом (по логике отдалённо напоминает `alias_method_chain` в Ruby).